# Copy Array to Object in Object with Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-factory

I'm learning Angular and I'm doing some example to understand angular.copy. What I want to do is create an Object with a Service, and then create a new Object which contains some element of the Service's Object.

Full code example: [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/BilQn6bcv4C0ziYJ7x65?p=preview)

This is the "Data" Object of the Service:

```
return {
    name: "hello",
    toys: ["asd", "lol"],
    food: ["apple"],
    phones: ["samsung", "lg", "iphone"]
};
```

In the Controller I copy the Object, create a new one, and copy into it just some element of the old Object:

```
$scope.oldData = angular.copy(Data);
$scope.newData = {};

$scope.newData.name = oldData.name;

$scope.newData.toys = oldData.toys;

$scope.newData.phones = oldData.phones;
```

What I expect is that the user display just three elements: the name, the toys array and the phones array:

```
    <h1>{{newData.name}}</h1>

<h1>Toys:</h1>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="toy in newData.toys">{{ toy }}</li>
</ul>


<h1>Phones:</h1>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="phone in newData.phones">{{ phone }}</li>
</ul>
```

Why does it not work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, you need to specify the source and destination like this angular.copy(source, [destination]); So I would assume something like this angular.copy(Data, $scope.oldData);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oldData` is scope variable, not normal javascript variable.

```
$scope.oldData
```

instead of

```
oldData
```

**Code**

```
$scope.oldData = angular.copy(Data);
$scope.newData = {};

$scope.newData.name = $scope.oldData.name;

$scope.newData.toys = $scope.oldData.toys;

$scope.newData.phones = $scope.oldData.phones;
```

---

Or either way you could make it `var oldData`

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/j3SmkLZYF3OWsx6Hi9dE?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You have not added $scope before using oldData. Check updated plunkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/znoKheLX3aMVHpNo7lh4?p=preview

```
 $scope.oldData = angular.copy(Data);
 $scope.newData = {};

 $scope.newData.name = $scope.oldData.name;

 $scope.newData.toys = $scope.oldData.toys;

 $scope.newData.phones = $scope.oldData.phones;
```

Answer (score 2):

you re using oldData but you ve defined $scope.oldData

```
     var oldData = angular.copy(Data);
     $scope.newData = {};

     $scope.newData.Name = oldData.name;

     $scope.newData.toys = oldData.toys;

     $scope.newData.phones = oldData.phones;
```

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AI7OWjlyHFXzyhgaAbZ7) the fixed plunker

Answer (score 1):

you have to write the scope object 
$scope.newData.name = $scope.oldData.name;
...

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code the error i got was `oldData is not defined`. That is because you are using `$scope.newData.Name = oldData.name;` but javascript engine cannot find a variable `oldData` in this scope.

You have oldData attached to the `$Scope`. So you have to use `$scope.newData.Name = $scope.oldData.name;`